How do I find logs for changes in Billing ID's in Google Cloud?
A few weeks ago I swapped a project's Billing Account per a user request. It seems that their filestore was somehow tied to the original Billing ID and now we cannot open it. How do I find logs in Google Cloud to determine what the original Billing ID is?

Have you try with google support?
